# How do I explore of the feasibility of using difference in days spent at home to assess outcomes after surgery?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, statistical-power, post-hoc

I have done a observational study testing a hypothesis something like this "Days alive and out of hospital for one year after surgery is more than one year before surgery". My data looks something like below. The actual sample size of the study is small ($n = 90$) for testing a hypothesis such as I have.

```
library (data.table)
mydata = as.data.table(participant.id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),  before.daoh = c(350, 340, 223, 340, 333,345,298,300), after.daoh = c(360, 340, 340, 320, 335, 345, 320, 310), age_year = c(40, 50, 50, 67, 78, 45, 67, 59), gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male"), indication = c("appendicitis","appendicitis","appendicitis", "hernia","appendicitis", "hernia","appendicitis", "hernia")
```

I have a total of 10 other columns with categorical variables. I want to do a post-hoc power analysis and plot the power against the sample size. I referred to previous studies and found an effect size of -3 and -4. How to do I calculate the level of significance from this?

Steps:

1. Reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis using paired t-test.
2. Look into variables that predicts DAOH?
3. Identify the feasibility of using DAOH to assess the outcomes after surgery
4. Plot probability on y-axis and sample size on x-axis.

Can you guys please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

##### Post-Hoc Power

It is too late now, but you should have conducted an a-priori power analysis (one done before the sampling was conducted). It is often recommended to *not* conduct post-hoc power analysis. A large reason for this is because the participants are assumed to be randomly sampled from population of interest. Once the data is observed, this random component no longer exists in terms of power probability (Zhang et al., 2019). Summarizing a bunch of points made by Lakens, 2022:

- Post-hoc power is directly related to the p value of the statistical test, and is consequently weighted.
- For a z-test where the p value is exactly $0.05$, post-hoc power is always $50$%. The reason for this relationship is that when a p value is observed that equals the alpha level of the test (e.g., $0.05$), the observed z score of the test is exactly equal to the critical value of the test (e.g., $z = 1.96$ in a two-sided test with a $5$% alpha level). Therefore any adjustment of observed p-values will change how one can interpret power, which isn't realistic.
- Whenever the alternative hypothesis is centered on the  critical value half the values we expect to observe if this alternative hypothesis is true fall below the critical value, and half fall above the critical value. Therefore, a test where we observed a p value identical to the alpha level will have exactly $50$% power in a post-hoc power analysis, as the analysis assumes the observed effect size is true.

##### Testing Procedure

Ideally, your testing should go instead like this:

1. Derive hypothesis that you want to test.
2. Design study (including which variables are theoretically necessary), create sampling procedure, and plan data collection.
3. Conduct a-priori power analysis to check how many participants should be used to acquire adequate statistical power.
4. Sample subjects.
5. Conduct analysis using statistical procedure that best answers your hypothetical question.

You have done so in a more backwards way. You have already collected the sample, want to fit a hypothesis to this after-the-fact, and then conduct a power analysis. This isn't the best procedure and should be amended the next time you do an analysis. Of course, with secondary data analysis, this changes to a degree, but you still wouldn't conduct post-hoc power analysis regardless.

##### References

- Lakens, D. (2022). Sample size justification. *Collabra: Psychology, 8*(1), 33267.
- Zhang, Y., Hedo, R., Rivera, A., Rull, R., Richardson, S., & Tu, X. M. (2019). Post hoc power analysis: Is it an informative and meaningful analysis? *General Psychiatry, 32*(4), e100069. https://doi.org/10.1136/gpsych-2019-100069

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I agree that post-hoc analysis gets a bit of bad rap. However, what are my other options here to explore the feasibility of using DAOH to assess the outcomes after surgery?

Comment: What do you mean by feasibility?

Comment: What is the probability of using DAOH as a parameter to assess the outcome?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what "probability of $x$ as a parameter for assessing an outcome" could possibly mean. Could you clarify further?

Comment: If you're asking whether or not you should use this variable, that should be entirely driven by past research and theory.